Why does my query from a pre-populated database return undefined?
Trying to get a list from table Nouns from a pre-populated database React Native is returning undefined. I added the pre-populated database in Android:
For IOS I just created a new assets folder and placed the database file within it. When I run the query in SQLite browser I do get the result:
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import SQLite from 'react-native-sqlite-storage';

export const getNouns = () =>{
const [nouns, setNouns] = useState([]);

const db = SQLite.openDatabase({
    name: 'DictionaryG.db',
    createFromLocation: 1
})

useEffect(() => {
    db.transaction((tx) => {
      tx.executeSql('SELECT Definition FROM Nouns limit 1',
      [],
      (tx, results) => {
        var temp = [];
        console.log(results)
        for (let i = 0; i < results.rows.length; ++i)
          temp.push(results.rows.item(i));
        setNouns(temp);
      });
    });
  }, [])

  return nouns;
}

